# Increase Unity dash opacity in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: unity

Is it possible to set `opacity=100` (no transparency) for the Unity dash (search)? I am not talking about `blur` effect. When I set `no blur` then the Unity dash looks fully transparent. To reduce the load I want to disable the blur effect as well as set the opacity to `100`. I am using `Ubuntu 13.10 64bit.`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how useful this is, since you might not like your Dash to be black...

Setting the Dash to `no blur` with the CompizConfig Settings Manager used to do this, but no longer. Using Unity Tweak you can make it opaque, but with the caveat that the Dash must be black. Selecting any other color will mean it's still transparent.

To install Unity Tweak, copy this into a terminal: `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`

Open the program, and in the `Unity` section click on `Launcher`. Then move the transparency slider to the left, and select a custom color. While any color will make the launcher opaque, only black will allow the Dash itself to be opaque.

[image: Unity Tweak Tool Launcher settings]